# I saw Mary two years ago for the last time

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> It's been 2 years since I saw Mary for the last time.

implies I won't see Mary forever.

I wonder whether the following sentence also means the same:

> I saw Mary two years ago for the last time.

Comment: The word order is unnatural, unless _for the last time_ is an afterthought. We would normally say "I saw Mary for the last time two years ago."

Comment: The alternative wording, if you expect to see Mary again sometime in the future, is "I last saw Mary two years ago". "the last time" in your and Kate's context implies there won't be another time.